# JavaScript regex for image attribute

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to get the image URL from these pages:

`http://www.amazon.co.uk/The-Classics-3xCD-Box-Set/dp/B000W3Q4X2/ref=sr_1_fkmr0_1/277-3029293-0823745?ie=UTF8&qid=1410727619&sr=8-1-fkmr0&keywords=Classic+Euphoria+3xCD+Box+Chicane+Hybrid+++P%26P`

`http://www.amazon.co.uk/Hinari-HIN172-Digital-Steam-Generator/dp/B00472M9S8/ref=sr_1_fkmr0_1/280-9070877-0582850?ie=UTF8&qid=1410725454&sr=8-1-fkmr0&keywords=Hinari+HIN172+2500+W+Digital+Steam+Generator+BOXED`

The image can be found in the `data-a-dynamic-image` attribute of the `img` tag within the `imgTagWrapperId` div.

The final image should be returned as:

`http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81Vi7ECR9hL.jpg`

E.g. The `_SX522_` should be removed from the original image URL which is `http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81Vi7ECR9hL._SX522_.jpg`

I only need to return one of the images from the source.

Comment: do you even know if you would encouter same-domain origin policy problems ?

Comment: you should get started by using indexOf and substring

Comment: Hi @johnSmith - I'll be making a copy of the image and uploading elsewhere. Do you know a regex I can use rather than string manipulation? Thanks

Comment: Why no "string manipulation"? What regexp have you tried yet?

Answer (score 0):

```
$html=file_get_contents('http://www.amazon.co.uk/The-Classics-3xCD-Box-Set/dp/B000W3Q4X2/ref=sr_1_fkmr0_1/277-3029293-0823745?ie=UTF8&qid=1410727619&sr=8-1-fkmr0&keywords=Classic+Euphoria+3xCD+Box+Chicane+Hybrid+++P%26P');
$html = preg_replace('/\s{2,}/', ' ', $html); // replace all instances of more than one whitespace with a single space
preg_match('/\{\&quot\;(https?\:\/\/[\S]+)\&quot\;/', $html, $matches); // can be either http or https potentially?
print_r($matches);
```

> Array (
>
> ```
> [0] => {&quot;http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41pi9o3crTL.jpg&quot;
> [1] => http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41pi9o3crTL.jpg
> ```
>
> )

The same regex works in Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('imgTagWrapperId').outerHTML.match(/\{\&quot\;(https?\:\/\/[\S]+)\&quot\;/);
["{&quot;http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41pi9o3crTL.jpg&quot;", "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41pi9o3crTL.jpg"]
```